# adding a line feed when building a string php

Tags: php

i have been looking all over and i cant find the answer. i am sure this is easy

i am sending an email, and in the body are names of clients

the code looks for clients that fit the search conditions and as each one is found it goes into a loop

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
 $clients = $clients . $first_name . ???
}
```

the result should be

```
Client1
Client2
Client3
```

but what i keep getting is:

```
Client1Client2Client3
```

I have tried

```
     $clients = $clients . $first_name . lf;
     $clients = $clients . $first_name . cr;
     $clients = $clients . $first_name . '\n';
```

but always the same result

TIA

Comment: Where are you outputting this? If you're outputting this in HTML it's `<br />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your output will be the command line, file, etc. Use `PHP_EOL`. If it will be a web browser use `<br>`:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $clients = $clients . $first_name . PHP_EOL;
}

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $clients = $clients . $first_name . "<br/>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `"\n"` or `PHP_EOL` (single quoted strings like `'\n'` are not interpolated)

```
$clients = $clients . $first_name . PHP_EOL;
```

If you're outputting this to the browser, newline characters are not displayed in html, so you can do something like this:

```
print nl2br($clients);
```

Or this:

```
header('Content-type: text/plain');
print $clients;`
```

Or this:

```
printf('<pre>%s</pre>', $clients);
```

Comment: Thanks, I spent several hours looking for this explanation.

Answer (score 0):

For text e-mails, the simplest case would be:

```
$clients = $clients . $first_name . "\n";
```

Note that you need to enclose `\n` in double (") instead of single (`) quotes, so that it gets treated as a new line character.

If you are sending HTML e-mails, then you'll need the appropriate HTML tag, i.e. `<br>`